# Getting zero 0 in the input model of livewire

Tags: laravel-livewire-wiremodel

hello evey one,  on laravel in use livewire, and i have a problème, (please help me)

I have a problème with livewire, and i don't understand why is'nt work

When i try to type something in the input model it's somethime return 0 in the box

thanks for help,